# How to represent a random variable in a program

Tags: probability-theory

I am not sure whether stack overflow is the right place to ask this question or not, but I am curious as to how to represent a random variable.

Say a random variable `X ~ N(mu, sigma)` then we can represent it by its mean and co variance separately. However, I know this can only be done for Gaussian distribution. If I want to represent a Poisson distribution, then this data type can no longer hold my Random Variable.

My question boils down, are there any languages/ libraries where I represent a random variable, like any other data structure. Personally I find it very difficult to understand the concept of random variable and such a representation would be great.
My ideal concept would be

`RandomVariable rv = new RandomVariable(mu, sigma) // Assume 1-Dimension as of now`

I know that in MATLAB, there is a function `mvnpdf()` which gives an instance of the distribution, but there is no notion of representing a random variable,

Comment: What is it that you want to do with this random variable once you've got it? Show us how you might imagine using it.

Comment: one possible use case would be `X1 ~ N(mu1, sigma1)` and `X2 ~ N(mu2, sigma2)`, I want to find out what is `X1 + X2`

Comment: A variable holds a value which is meaningful to you. A few languages have libraries that will instantiate an instance of different types of random number distributions. You then poll/read this instance repeatedly to get you range of values. Some users will build the boost random library which is written mostly in C++. Small portions might or used to be in C. This build can provide dlls that you can call from your language. Different instances returning different types as in int, real real48 or real64 maybe long long which can be 80 bit in certain Intel FPUs sections

Answer (score 0):

In general, for a programming language, you don't declare a random variable, so much as you create a function that generates (pseudo)random numbers according to whatever distribution you want to use. There are many libraries for generating random numbers, and the most common are typically Gaussian distributed. When programming you have to try to think in terms of unambiguous steps to solve a problem you want to solve rather than a particular abstract notation which while useful, may not correspond directly to an algorithm. Most likely you will use random numbers generated from the selected random number generating function as input to a function which substitutes into your abstract model and produces a set of values that constitute a single sample of your statistical evaluation of the model.